# How do I turn this date into a python datetime object?

Tags: python, string, datetime, time

I want a datetime object, but I have strings in this format:

```
2010-10-06T08:12:41Z
```

How do I turn that into a datetime object?

Comment: Search.  That's how it's done.  Your question has been asked.  And asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving a date from a complex string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070175/retrieving-a-date-from-a-complex-string-in-python)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python are pretty good duplicates of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.strptime(timestring, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

it's in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("2010-10-06T08:12:41Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```